# How to use Visual Studio Online source control with VFP 9 SP1

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-foxpro

How can I use this [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs) source control with a visual foxpro (vfp) 9 sp1 project so that the VFP does automatic check in and check out as I change files and lets me undo or check in source code and view history like I can do in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE with dot net projects?

I see there's a free [team explorer everywhere](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs#Fragment_ProductFeatures) which i guess i can use outside of the vfp IDE - not sure how it will handle the SCX, FRX, LBX, PRJ files which are not textual.

Comment: I think VSO can be used only with VS 2012 or 2013.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can't use VSO with Visual FoxPro 9, but surely you can use other SCM tools with Visual FoxPro, like SVN, Mercurial, PlasticSCM (which I use), etc.

For Diff and Merge you can use a new tool found on VFPx project, called FoxBin2Prg, that allow bidirectional conversion of VFP 9 binaries to text and vice-versa, so you even can modify the generated text version and rebuild the binary.

More info at [FoxBin2Prg - Binary/Text Conversor for Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9](https://github.com/fdbozzo/foxbin2prg).

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this question while researching. Looks like Microsoft updated the MSSCCI to be used with Visual Foxpro

Install the Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013&2015 MSSCCI Provider 32 bit : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8

It supports Visual FoxPro 9 SP2 connection to Visual Studio Online

Combined with the Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, you can branch, forward integrate, reverse integrate. I'm still exploring it

Comment: It surprisingly works with VFP8 once it is setup with VFP9 SP2. I can open the project in VFP8. Checkout/checkin right from the project will use the MSSCCI dialogs. Combined with Microsoft Team Explorer 2013 it worked just like the old Source Safe, with additional Branching/FI/RI/Shelving features.

Comment: Thank you for reply, we will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful when you get the chance :)

Comment: Hi, I install MSSCCI provider and integrate to VFP IDE successfully. Then I trought add existing project to source control. First step, PJM file with project info and without file list, was success, Second step, adding files, was success. Then I trought update project list for adding file list to PJM, checkin was success, but after that, VFP trought update project from PJM and error " cannot update project from project metafile" occurs. Any ideas? More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889146/tfs-msscci-provider-with-visual-fox-pro-9-sp2-cannot-update-project-from-proje

Comment: 'Solution' here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889146/tfs-msscci-provider-with-visual-fox-pro-9-sp2-cannot-update-project-from-proje

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you. From Jesse's comment, seems like the only difference why mine works is that I use server workspace configuration.

Comment: This is my workspace setting (using Source Control Explorer from VS2015) : server (<my VSO server>), Location (Server), File Time (Current), Permission (Public Workspace)

Comment: 1:add a new project in VSO. 2:Create new project in VFP9Sp2. 3:Add a blank form with button. 4:Menu Project/Add project to Source Control (click Check-In). 5:Menu Project/Source Control/Update Project List. I also tried starting with blank project, then update project list, before adding a form, and it went smoothly.

Comment: I've got same workspace setting, only permission is Private Workspace. I think it's project specific problem.

Comment: There was problem in PJM file - one file path contained comma.
It's a pity that IDE didn't show detailed error message about syntax error (for example line number). Finding this one line in thousands lines was hard.

Comment: Very nice. Now if we can figure out how to compare scx/vcx it would be most useful.

Comment: Peter, have you some experiences with offline working with MSSCCI provider? Some unresolvable problems?

Comment: Not really, care to elaborate?

Comment: Not yet. First I will try some tests. Maybe later. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can't, and the main reason is that while PRG and other textual files are fine method code and other stuff is stored in DBF-format files, which your chosen source control software will treat as binary.

Comment: aren't prg files treated as text files? the binary might be correct for scx, frx, and prj files - but not for .prg right?

Comment: Right. Back in the day there were plugins for Visual SourceSafe that could handle the source code embedded in the VCX/SCX and so on, diff it etc. but nothing like that exists for VS Online.

Comment: do you think this Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 MSSCCI Provider would work with vfp 9 spy? it says it works on vfp 9 spy http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8

Comment: Even if it does not work you can have Team Explorer open side by side with FoxPro. You can then exit in FoxPro but manage source in Team Explorer.

Comment: As mentioned above, there are bi-directional tools that allow you to convert between VFP binary files and plain text