# TFS MSSCCI Provider with Visual Fox Pro 9 SP2 - cannot update project from project metafile

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops, visual-foxpro, msscci

I have existing project in Visual Fox Pro 9 SP2. I added this project to source control over VFP IDE with MSSCCI provider integrated, then I added files to source control. Everything was ok, but then I **update project list** and error

> "cannot update project from project metafile"

occurs.

Same error is shown when I try join source controlled project to other workspace.

There is problem with PJM file ([error description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976421%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on msdn), but I don't know how solve it. I did not change file manually, there is no conflict and there is no format problem because it was generated automatically by tool.

Can somebody explain me why I have this problem and how solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Which version of TFS  are you using? Is this only occurs with the specific project or every project file?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Online. I try only one project , so maybe specific for this project. I try remove PJM file and then regenerate it using Update project File command in IDE, then checkin, and error again, no manually edited.

Comment: Nobody using VFP with Visual Studio Team Services over MSSCCI?

Comment: Check that your workspace has been set to a "Server Workspace" MSSCCI and Local workspaces don't work well together.

Comment: Also check whether all files were actually added to source control. It looks as though it may be that some files are currently controlled, while others are only on your local file system. using Team Explorer's Source Control explorer allows you to compare the Workspace against your disk to search for differences.

Comment: Also make sure all files are actually saved when checking in. Personally I've mostly stopped using MSSCCI in any project and manually managed files in source control using either the Windows Explorer integration from the power tools or Team Explorer in a separate VS2015 installation.

Comment: Thank you. I trought all what you wrote but problem still occurs. I will try other way for VFP source control. It's a pity.

Comment: I just tried it with VFP and MSSCCI but cannot reproduce this issue. Can you share your detailed steps?

Comment: 1. Add project to source control - checkin new PJM (only project info part, without ProjectFiles) - OK
2. Add included files to source control - check in one by one - OK
3. Update project list - adding ProjectFiles part, checkin OK, then MSSCCI try update project and error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found file path with problem - path contains comma :)

> sestavy\katalog\seznam šarží, sériových čísel.frx

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pjm started from blank project created in Vfp 9 Sp2. (sorry for the d) It works with VSTS (or VSO). Checking in/out new files, Update project List works smoothly. Can you compare it with yours? Just like jessehouwing's answer, please make sure it's your workspace is server workspace.

```
Version=  1.20  
Author=  
Company=  
Address=  
City=  
State=  
Zip=  
Country=  
SaveCode=.T.  
Debug=.T.  
Encrypt=.F.  
NoLogo=.F.  
CommentStyle=1  
Comments=  
CompanyName=  
FileDescription=  
LegalCopyright=  
LegalTrademarks=  
ProductName=  
Major=  
Minor=  
Revision=  
AutoIncrement=.F.  
[OLEServers]  
[OLEServersEnd]  
[ProjectFiles]  
1218598277,K,vfpintegration2.scx,.F.,.T.,1252,,,  
1218598357,P,vfpintegration2.prg,.F.,.F.,1252,,,  
1218598458,P,vfpintegration2hello.prg,.F.,.F.,1252,,,  
[EOF]
```

Also check the steps in my comment from 
[How to use Visual Studio Online source control with VFP 9 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580769/how-to-use-visual-studio-online-source-control-with-vfp-9-sp1/33147581?noredirect=1#comment61524953_33147581)

Comment: I believe that new project will work. Hovewer there is probably problem with existing project. Interesting is, that PJM is generated by IDE and contains some problem which cause this error. There is a lot files and finding THIS ONE witch cause problem is difficult. Workspace is Server.